# How to remove the axes tick marks in plots from plotly?

Tags: javascript, python, plotly, data-visualization, data-analysis

[image: Scatterplot using plotly]
How do I format this better? I create unordered pairs from list of columns and plotting them iteratively. I havent managed to remove the axis tick labels. Any suggestions on howto format this better so that I display it in front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you have not indicated how you are building the sub-plots
- you can make all axis invisible with `fig.update_layout({ax:{"visible":False, "matches":None} for ax in fig.to_dict()["layout"] if "axis" in ax})`
- full example code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

L = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "lin": np.linspace(0, 100, L),
        "cos": np.cos(np.linspace(0, np.pi, L)),
        "sin": np.sin(np.linspace(0, np.pi, L)),
        "tan": np.tan(np.linspace(0, np.pi, L)),
        "char": np.random.choice(list("ABCDEF"), L),
        "rand": np.random.uniform(1,50, L)
    }
)

fig = px.scatter(
    df.stack().reset_index(), x="level_0", y=0, facet_col="level_1", facet_col_wrap=3
)
fig.update_layout({ax:{"visible":False, "matches":None} for ax in fig.to_dict()["layout"] if "axis" in ax})
```

- matrix of all columns against all columns. Hide tick marks

```
px.scatter_matrix(df).update_layout({ax:{"tickmode":"array","tickvals":[]} for ax in fig.to_dict()["layout"] if "axis" in ax})
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using `plt.subplots(x, y)` here. To remove axes (including there text) completely, you can use `subplot[x, y].axis('off')`.
Alternatively, you could add more space in between the plots with `plt.margins(x_y_margin)` or `plt.margins(x_margin, y_margin)`.

A little bit offtopic: I wouldn't use scatter plots for visualization of classes (like in the plot 2nd row 3rd column).